# PWA running when http-server is stopped

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, httpserver, angular-pwa

I am using http-server to deploy my angular app on my computer just for doing some performance tests.

Here is the results of the deployment:
[image]

And when I stop the server, the terminal tells me that http-server is stopped:
[image]

I used netstat to make sure the port 8081 is not opened:

[image]

But for some reasons, I still can run my application. May be the reason is that it is a PWA but I'm not sure.

Do you think that the reason my app remains alive is because it is a PWA? If not do you have any idea about what could be the reason?

Comment: Well, you can check the network tab in the devtools to see if your app is currently provided by a service worker.

Comment: Thank you @Mike S,
I just read about the service worker. I installed it to make my angular app a PWA  without knowing exactly what it adds for the user experience. Now I know.
Now I know the reason the interface responds even when the application is offline. :)